# How to solve "No Activity found to handle Intent" error

Tags: android, eclipse

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.suven.Create_memo }
```

I just want to go from one activity to another but its giving me this error.

my main activity code is as folllow

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            try
            {
                Intent i=new Intent("com.android.suven.Create_memo");
            startActivity(i);
            }
            catch ( ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });  
    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            try
            {
                Intent i=new Intent("com.android.suven.Create_memo");
            startActivity(i);
            }
            catch ( ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    });          
  }
}
```

My logcat is like this:

```
06-05 13:43:35.959: E/AndroidRuntime(275): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 13:43:35.959: E/AndroidRuntime(275): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.suven/com.android.suven.Create_memo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-05 13:43:35.959: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
06-05 13:43:35.959: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-05 13:43:35.959: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-05 13:43:35.959: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-05 13:43:35.959: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-05 13:43:35.959: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-05 13:43:35.959: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-05 13:43:35.959: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 13:43:35.959: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-05 13:43:35.959: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-05 13:43:35.959: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-05 13:43:35.959: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 13:43:35.959: E/AndroidRuntime(275): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-05 13:43:35.959: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.android.suven.Create_memo.onCreate(Create_memo.java:56)
06-05 13:43:35.959: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-05 13:43:35.959: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-05 13:43:35.959: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  ... 11 more
06-05 13:43:39.199: I/Process(275): Sending signal. PID: 275 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Did you add you Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Hi @shubh you should addd your activity name in the AdroidManifest.xml file with your packagedecleration or without decleration.

Comment: ya i added my activity in menifest bt still it is giving an error.. i hav tried all the syntax of intent bt not working n getting same error everytime.

Comment: Post byour log here for displaying java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: NW IT IS GIVING ME THIS ERROR

Answer (score 3):

in your code-line

```
Intent i=new Intent("com.android.suven.Create_memo");
```

**"com.android.suven.Create_memo"**  is taken as ACTION.

Instead, you have to put

```
Intent i=new Intent(YourCurrentAivityName.this, Create_memo.class);
```

Also put

```
<activity
            android:name=".Create_memo" >
        </activity>
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared Create_memo activity in your manifest file? like:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.android.suven.Create_memo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is NextActivity.java

```
public class NextActivity extends Activity {

//Your member variable declaration here

// Called when the activity is first created.
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//Your code here
}
}
```

After creation of a new Activity, we have to register it in file ‘AndroidManifest.xml’.
For registering we have to create an entry in ‘AndroidManifest.xml’ as

```
**<activity android:name=".NextActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"/>**
```