# ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

This report I recive from google play, my app crash on :

```
  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.common.account.CHOOSE_ACCOUNT (has extras) }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1518)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1390)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3204)
at com.example.uploadvideo.MainUploadToYoutube.authenticate(MainUploadToYoutube.java:287)
at com.example.uploadvideo.MainUploadToYoutube.onOptionsItemSelected(MainUploadToYoutube.java:211)
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2516)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:965)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:468)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:126)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4508)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

in `com.example.uploadvideo.MainUploadToYoutube` I have this methood :

```
public void authenticate() {
    Intent accountChooserIntent =
        AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
            new String[] {GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE}, true, "Select an account", null,
            null, null);
    startActivityForResult(accountChooserIntent, REQUEST_PICK_ACCOUNT);
  }



 case REQUEST_PICK_ACCOUNT:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          mChosenAccountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
          tryAuthenticate();
        }
```

I find these [similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614561/android-content-activitynotfoundexception-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-sp)  , [How to solve “No Activity found to handle Intent” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880026/how-to-solve-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-error)

from these post I understand that I need to rewrite the intent and add activity to the manifest am I right ???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you are using a Google Play Services component (the AccountPicker), you need to ensure that Google Play Services exists and is up to date on the users device before calling methods that use the service as explained in the [setup guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure).

Comment: @idan - in almost all cases, Google Play Services will have auto-updated on the user's device and be perfectly valid. It is those rare edge cases such as users who refuse to update from the old Android Market to Google Play Store (which is what downloads updates to Google Play Services).