# CHOOSE_ACCOUNT intent exception crash outside Google Play

Tags: android, android-activity, google-play, amazon-appstore

I got via Firebase console the following crash:

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException 
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.common.account.CHOOSE_ACCOUNT pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) }
keyboard_arrow_up 

android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult (Instrumentation.java:1794) 
arrow_drop_down 
android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:3706) 
arrow_right 
it.***.Mm_Registration$2.onClick (Unknown Source) 

android.view.View.performClick (View.java:4780) 
arrow_drop_down 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

And I reckon it comes from Amazon App Store market, so I guess the account picker doesn't work with it...any workaround except to write different apps, one with `GET_ACCOUNTS permission` and retrieve the account in "old style" and the other one with `account picker`?

EDIT 1:
I had already attended the post you all linked but it didn't solve my problem at all since I already check whether Google Play Service is uptodate, as following:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data)
{
    if ( requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES && resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED )
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services must be installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }
}

private boolean checkPlayServices()
{
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
    {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status))
        {
          showErrorDialog(status);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void showErrorDialog(int code)
{
    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(code, this, REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES).show();
}
static final int REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES = 1001;

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if (!checkPlayServices())
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Service unavailable. Exit.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478471/activitynotfoundexception-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent)

Comment: I read that post already and it doesn't provide a solution

Comment: I've edited the first post